# Nextjs: How to set env for dev to be different from env for build?

Tags: next.js

I have a question about Nextjs
How to set env for dev to be different from env for build?

Comment: Have you read this section of docs about envs? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables If so, could you please elaborate on your question, for example what have you tried already etc.

Answer (score 0):

In the docu you can find solution here: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables

> In general only one .env.local file is needed. However, sometimes you might want to add some defaults for the development (next dev) or production (next start) environment. Next.js allows you to set defaults in .env (all environments), .env.development (development environment), and .env.production (production environment).

Be aware NOT to store secrets in files uploaded to version control like Github!

Answer (score -1):

in my next.config.js

```
// Environment configs
const DOTENVPATH = `../.env.${process.env.APP_ENV}.local`
require('dotenv').config({ path: DOTENVPATH })
```